# OpenVZ : live migration fails

Tags: iptables, virtualization, migration, openvz, proxmox

I can't launch live migration of OpenVZ container between two proxmox nodes...

```
Feb 05 03:30:27 starting migration of CT 102 to node 'madrid' (xx.xx.xx.xx)
Feb 05 03:30:27 container is running - using online migration
Feb 05 03:30:27 starting rsync phase 1
Feb 05 03:30:27 # /usr/bin/rsync -aHAX --delete --numeric-ids --sparse /var/lib/vz/private/102 root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/var/lib/vz/private
Feb 05 03:30:36 start live migration - suspending container
Feb 05 03:30:36 dump container state
Feb 05 03:30:36 # vzctl --skiplock chkpnt 102 --dump --dumpfile /var/lib/vz/dump/dump.102
Feb 05 03:30:36 Setting up checkpoint...
Feb 05 03:30:36     join context..
Feb 05 03:30:36     dump...
Feb 05 03:30:36 Can not dump container: Invalid argument
Feb 05 03:30:36 Error: iptables-save exited with 1
Feb 05 03:30:36 ERROR: Failed to dump container state: Checkpointing failed
Feb 05 03:30:36 aborting phase 1 - cleanup resources
Feb 05 03:30:36 removing copied files on target node
Feb 05 03:30:37 start final cleanup
Feb 05 03:30:37 ERROR: migration aborted (duration 00:00:10): Failed to dump container state: Checkpointing failed
TASK ERROR: migration aborted
```

I have iptables-persistent installed on both nodes, and on the container to migrate.
iptables-save output is well expected...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks by advance !